# Resolve Cyclic Dependency on hierarchical data between two tables

Tags: c#, sql, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core 3.1 with SQL Server and I have a survey app that has questions. A Survey has one ore more questions. Each question may have one or more options. This can extend to unlimited levels. e.g

```
What is your Country?
|
|--France
|--United Kingdom
|--United States
   |---What is your state?
       |---New York
       |---Alaska
       |---California
           |---What is your City?
               |--- Los Angeles
               |--- San Diego
               |--- San Francisco
```

My code is the following:

```
public class Survey
{
    public Survey()
    {
        Questions = new HashSet<Question>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // A Survey may have one or more than one questions
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public Question()
    {
        Options = new HashSet<Option>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string QuestionText { get; set; }


    // A Survey may have one or more than one questions
    public long? SurveyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }


    // A Question may have one or more than one options
    public virtual ICollection<Option> Options { get; set; }

    // An Option may have one or more Questions 
    public long? ParentOptionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Option ParentOption { get; set; }
}

public class Option
{
    public Option()
    {
        SubQuestions = new HashSet<Question>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string OptionText { get; set; }

    // A Question may have one or more than one options
    public long ParentQuestionid { get; set; }
    public virtual Question ParentQuestion { get; set; }

    // An Option may have one or more Questions 
    public virtual ICollection<Question> SubQuestions { get; set; }
}


public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Survey> Survey { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Question> Question { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Option> Option { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Survey>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasMany(x => x.Questions)
                .WithOne(x => x.Survey)
                .IsRequired();
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Question>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasMany(x => x.Options)
                .WithOne(x => x.ParentQuestion)
                .IsRequired()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Option>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasMany(x => x.SubQuestions)
                .WithOne(x => x.ParentOption)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        });
    }
}
```

My problem here is that the relationships from Question to Option (A Question has one or many options and  that question can belong to one option) causes cyclic reference. How can I resolve cyclic reference in my case which cause problems to Cascades
I am using code first and I think my domain logic which I described at the beginning of this post is correct. I don't see any other way of doing this. Can anyone assist?

Update #1:
When I run Update-Database I get:

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Question_Option_ParentOptionId' on table 'Question' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

Comment: What is the exception and when do you get it? From executing update-database, data insertion or where?

Comment: @jegtugado Sorry forgot to add the issue when I run Update-Database

Comment: The problem is, that an option can be the parent option of a question and also a child at the same time. AFAIK you cannot use cascade delete in this case and you have to handle it manually

Comment: I would prefer to avoid recursion calls to delete something. Is there any alternative?

Comment: You could use a NoSQL database :o)

Comment: :) No that will violate project requirements.

Comment: Yeah, I think so - but you have asked ;o)

Comment: I was looking for an alternative to my design

Comment: Your design contains all needed relations. I would say there is not really an alternative to it

Comment: My main worry is the cyclic reference. I know that is not the best thing to have cyclic references.

Comment: You have **possible** cyclic references - the business logic should take care that it will be only theory - thats why the message reads „may cause“

Comment: Introduce different model for sub questions.

Comment: Still what is the difference? Based on that this is hierarchical and can go to n level will have the same problem in next level

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple and it is already stated in the log during `Update-Database`. You can end the cyclic references by setting the OnDelete but make sure that you configure this based on how you want it to be.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Survey>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasMany(x => x.Questions)
            .WithOne(x => x.Survey)
            .IsRequired();
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Question>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasMany(x => x.Options)
            .WithOne(x => x.ParentQuestion)
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade); // You can also set this to NoAction if you prefer
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Option>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasMany(x => x.SubQuestions)
            .WithOne(x => x.ParentOption)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade); // Set to NoAction
    });
}
```

Comment: Cyclic reference cannot be ended based on the OnDeletes. ```make sure that you configure this based on how you want it to be.``` What do you mean exactly here?

Comment: My bad, the cyclic reference won't end but the error will by instructing EF to not perform cascade deletions.